# how to ignore 1st row while uploading excel sheet to MySQL using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, express

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res)=>{

var fileName = req.file;

console.log(fileName);

readXlsxFile(req.file.path).then((rows) => {

  console.log(rows);

  var con = mysql2.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "personal_db"
});

 con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
      var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO information (id, name) VALUES ?";
      var values = rows;
      // var finValue = values.trim();
      console.log(values);
      con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {

        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
      });
    });
    });
```

how to ignore 1st row of the excel while uploading excel sheet to MySQL using a query, its works by IGNORE but also inserts 1st row which consists of table headings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rows` object is an array. Before you use it you can remove its first element with [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```
rows.shift()
const values = rows
```

or, slightly faster, with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
const values = rows.slice(1)
```

**Pro tip** Try to avoid `var` unless you're developing browser code for obsolete browsers.